# How to Select data from SQL Server 2000 using distinct clause on ONLY 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I'm trying to select some customer information: name, address, city, state, and zip.  I'd like to pull all information and only pull of the records if there is a dupe.

Example of data:

```
 Invoice_Date First    Last    Addr       City     State     Zip
     11/11/14   Jim     Jones   12 Cedar   alkdjf     TN       29430
     11/11/15   Ralph   Jones   12 Cedar   alkdjf     TN       29430
     11/11/14   Robert  Smith   15 block   slkjdd     TX       10932
```

What I want to return:

```
Invoice_Date First    Last    Addr       City     State     Zip
     11/11/15   Ralph   Jones   12 Cedar   alkdjf     TN       29430 (newest Record)
     11/11/14   Robert  Smith   15 block   slkjdd     TX       10932
```

This is my query that is able to pull ALL customers for the specified dates:

```
SELECT     
    Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date, Invoice_Tb.Customer_First_Name, 
    Invoice_Tb.Customer_Last_Name, 
    Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address, Invoice_Tb.City, 
    Invoice_Tb.Customer_State, Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code
FROM
    Invoice_Tb 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Invoice_Detail_Tb ON Invoice_Tb.Store_Number = Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Number 
                      AND Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Number = Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Number 
                      AND Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date = Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date
WHERE     
    (Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date IN ('11/11/14', '11/11/15')) 
    AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Detail_Code = 'FSV') 
    AND (LEN(Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address) > 4)
ORDER BY 
    Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address
```

Now, obviously I can't use `Row_Number` here, because it's not an option in SQL Server 2000, so that's out.

I've tried `Select Distinct` - but I'm in need of the other information (first name, last name, etc), and when using select Distinct, it also returns distinct records for First and Last name.  I only want 1 record, per address.

How can I return 1 row, for each distinct Address while including first name last name of the MOST recent visit, in this case - 11/11/15.

Comment: What is the Primary Key of `Invoice_Tb`?    There is a pretty standard way of doing this in SQL 2000, but it requires that the table have a Unique key on it.

Comment: The Primary Key is Invoice_Number

Comment: You define a "Dupe" based off of the columns (Addr+City+State+Zip) and no others?

Comment: Dupe by ADDRESS only - I don't care about any other column.  I just want 1 result per Addr.

Comment: If so you need to select a min or max id, and Addr,City,Stat,Zip.  Get the min or max Id for that 4 column combination.  Then join that back to the original table by Id and do your select.  One select to determine which is the min or max, another select to pull all the columns you want to pull.

Comment: Address bring the combination of (Addr, City, State, Zip)?  Does the table have a unique id in it because it is needed in the query even though you don't want to display it in the final result.

Comment: See above - Invoice_Number

Comment: You just gave me an idea - Select distinct addr, max(id) That should work perfectly - let me try.

Comment: Bingo!  @MTHead - If you'd like to throw an answer together, I'll accept it as an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok.  Will do but I need the question answered is there an identity value in the table?  Can I fabricate one for my solution, because my method requires one.  If you don't have one it can still be done but gets much more confusing.

Comment: Invoice_Number, It's listed twice, above.

Comment: Now I see the invoice number, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #SomeTest (Invoice_Number Int, InvoiceDt DateTime, FName Varchar(24), LName Varchar(24), Addr Varchar(24), City Varchar(24), St Varchar(2), Zip Varchar(12) )

insert into #SomeTest (Invoice_Number, InvoiceDt, FName, LName, Addr, City, St, Zip) values (1, '11/11/14', 'Jim','Jones', '12 Cedar', 'alkdjf', 'TN', '29430')
insert into #SomeTest (Invoice_Number, InvoiceDt, FName, LName, Addr, City, St, Zip) values (2, '11/11/15', 'Ralph','Jones', '12 Cedar', 'alkdjf', 'TN', '29430')
insert into #SomeTest (Invoice_Number, InvoiceDt, FName, LName, Addr, City, St, Zip) values (3, '11/11/14', 'Robert','Smith', '15 block', 'slkjdd', 'TX', '10932')


select * from #SomeTest
where Invoice_Number in 
(
select Invoice_Number from 
   (select Invoice_Number = max(Invoice_Number), SupperAddy = Addr + '#' + City + '#' + St + '#' +  Zip from #SomeTest
   group by Addr + '#' + City + '#' + St + '#' +  Zip) X
)
```

Comment: Nested sub selects to the rescue.  Modify the select * from #SomeTest, to just pull the fields you want to see in the final results.

I think you want "Invoice_Date,First, Last, Addr, City, State,Zip"
My field names slightly different than yours but the logic works the same.

Comment: This assumes you want the highest number Invoice Number in selecting which of the "Dupes" to include.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this query:

```
SELECT
    i.last,
    MAX(invoice_date) AS InvoiceDAte,
    MAX(first) AS First,
    MAX(addr) AS addr,
    MAX(zip) AS zip
FROM invoice i
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    last,
    MAX(invoice_date) AS MaxInvoiceDate
FROM invoice
GROUP BY last) a
    ON a.last = i.last
    AND a.MaxInvoiceDate = i.Invoice_date
GROUP BY i.last
```

Here max(invoice_date) can be multiple in that case we require to take top 1 on that

Comment: That handles the max invoice date - but i'm not seeing where I select distinct Addresses, which is the major problem.

Comment: We can add one another group-by, see my updated query

Comment: Eventually it will get max(invoiceDate) has to get one max record, if it is not getting you will be having corresponding logic to get that max record.. In that case use that logic

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any analytic function (like row_number) then you could do something like this:

```
--This gives you the most recent date for an address
Select max(invoice_Date) as Invoice_date
Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address
, Invoice_Tb.City
, Invoice_Tb.Customer_State
, Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code
into #tmp1
from Invoice_Tb 
group by Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address
, Invoice_Tb.City
, Invoice_Tb.Customer_State
, Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code
GO

--link back to the name for the most recent address
Select a.Invoice_date
,b.Customer_First_Name as [First]
,b.Customer_Last_Name as [Last]
, a.Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address as [Addr]
, a.Invoice_Tb.City
, a.Invoice_Tb.Customer_State as [State]
, a.Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code as [Zip]
from #tmp1 a
left join Invoice_T b on 
a.Invoicedate = b.Invoicedate
a.Customer_Address = b.Customer_Address
a.City = b.City
a.Customer_State = b.Customer_State
a.ZIP_Code = b.ZIP_Code
GO
```

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use Row Number, it's that I can't, with 2000 - I'll have a look at this.

Comment: I don't have the documentation in front of me for SQL Server 2000.  Even if row number wasn't around back then there might be some alternative like dense_rank.  I tried looking it up but it is just too long ago.  It is hard to find some of the documentation for things prior to 2005.  I just figured it is easier to write the code without using an analytic function than to figure out what was available back then.

Comment: a subquery with group by and then min or max over the pk would work.

Comment: Sure.  The logic I did in my temp table could have just been done as a subquery.  It is just a style decision on my part.  I personally feel that kind of syntax is less readable when trying to read it on a web page.  Normally, I would actually write something like that as a common table expression.  However, CTE was not introduced until SQL Server 2005.  The best thing to do would be to move toward a newer version of SQL Server. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "standard" way I always did this in my MsSql 2000 days.   In your case, a subquery in the WHERE clause would also work, but I will use the INNER JOIN version of this solution.   I employed a little bit of pseudo-code to cut down on my typing.  You should be able to figure it out:

```
SELECT     
    t1.Invoice_Date, t1.Customer_First_Name, 
    t1.Customer_Last_Name, 
    t1.Customer_Address, t1.City, 
    t1.Customer_State, t1.ZIP_Code
FROM
    Invoice_Tb t1
INNER JOIN Invoice_Tb t2
    ON t1.Invoice_Number = (
      SELECT TOP 1 t2.Invoice_Number
      WHERE t2.Customer_Address=t1.Customer_Address
      AND {t2.City,State,Zip=t1.City,State,Zip} --psuedocode
      ORDER BY t2.Invoice_Date DESC
    )

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Invoice_Detail_Tb ON ...
WHERE     
   ...
ORDER BY 
    Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address
```

Also note that if any of the "address" fields can be NULL, you will have to handle that possibility when comparing them in the subquery.